# Google analytics V4 client access to our app

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4

We have a web application in PHP, for our clients we have prepared connect to google analytics UA. I use "google/apiclient": "^2.0", it works that our clients click on button in our administration and then is runned a followed code:

```
$this->client = new Google_Client(); 
$this->client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$this->client->setClientId("xxxx");
$this->client->setClientSecret("xxxx");
$this->client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"));
$this->client->setRedirectUri("xxxx");
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
```

The credentials i get from https://console.cloud.google.com/  -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

then the client is redirected to google where he log in, and allow acces to his GA data for our app. then is redirected back with code is generated access token. With this token i can get his GA UA data and show it to graphs in our administration. It works allright, but now i get information that GA UA will be end, and i need to create the same proces for UA V4. But in documentation to GA V4 what i found: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1
Is not information how to process it for our clients. There is only authorisation over service account, that i must donwload my own credentials.json to service account but it allow me only acces to my private account, but i need it to work the same as before, so for other clients without having to upload credentials.json. That is, to be redirected to google via OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and allow access to our application to read their data. Is it even possible?

Thank you for help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should have a look at the [PHP Google Analytics data client library](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data)  you can use this to connect to GA4 accounts.   There is currently only documentation for service account authorization.  But it does work with Oauth2.  You just need to create the proper client.  I have created an issue requesting that they document it. [5368](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/5368)

Comment: Yes there is only documentation for service account, but how i can do the connect over Oauth2, the PHP code to authorisation over oAuth for other clients not only for me is missing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a start. I am combining the OAuth2 methods from the  Google API php client library and applying them to the new library.

Its not optimal but it works.  Code below is for installed application not web. Its not going to work hosted.

```
<?php


require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Client;

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json');  // Installed / native / desktop Client credetinals.

$credentials =  getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');

$myfile = file_get_contents($credentials, "r") ;

$clientObj = json_decode($myfile);

$client = getClient();

$tokenResponse = $client->getAccessToken();

print_r($tokenResponse);
print_r($tokenResponse["access_token"]);


$service = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient( [
    'credentials' => Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::build( [
        'scopes'  => [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
            'openid',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        ],
        'keyFile' => [
            'type'          => 'authorized_user',
            'client_id'     => $clientObj->installed->client_id,
            'client_secret' => $clientObj->installed->client_secret,
            'refresh_token' => $tokenResponse["refresh_token"]
        ],
    ] ),
] );

$response = $service->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/[YOUR_PROPERTY_ID]'
]);

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getDimensionValues() as $dimensionValue) {
        print 'Dimension Value: ' . $dimensionValue->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}


function getClient()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google analytics data beta Oauth2');
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics');
    $client->setAuthConfig(getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you very much. And how i can get list of all GA4 properties of logged user?

Comment: You have to go though the Google analytics admin api to get profile info   [Google analytics admin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1) which uses this client library [PHP Analytics admin](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/main/AnalyticsAdmin)

Comment: Ok i understand it, and everything works. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

And please how to get list streams of listed properties, I have a code to get GA4 properties:

```
$this->SetGa4ClientAdmin();
$accounts = $this->ga4_admin->listAccounts();
$this->data['accounts_v4'] = array();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
  $this->data['accounts_v4'][$account->getName()] = array('name' => $account->getDisplayName(), 'childrens' => array());
  try {
    $properties = $this->ga4_admin->ListProperties('parent:' . $account->getName());
    foreach ($properties AS $property) {
      $this->data['accounts_v4'][$account->getName()]['childrens'][$property->getName()] = $property->getDisplayName();
    }
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    die("error: " . $ex->getMessage());
  }
}
```

At every property I need to get measurement ID of GA4 streams.

[I need to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ5nz.png)

Comment: i found that i can get list of streams on parent property:

$streams = $this->ga4_admin->listDataStreams($property->getName());

but when i call $stream->getMeasurementId() on one stream i get fatal error:

Call to undefined method Google\\Analytics\\Admin\\V1alpha\\DataStream::getMeasurementId()